# APYDataGridBundle getting access to original query or list of items

Tags: symfony, datagrid

```
$source = new Entity('MyEntity');
/* @var $grid Grid */
$grid = $this->get('grid');
$grid->setSource($source);
```

Anyone knows if is this possible to get original doctrine query that the grid executes to fill out itself with appropriate items from entity. All I need to do is to store in session ordered ids of all items that will be shown by grid.

Answer (score 1):

try this manipulateQuery() see docs:

https://github.com/Abhoryo/APYDataGridBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/grid_configuration/manipulate_query.md